# How to change SQL query to codeigniter model?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function get_department_list($limit, $start)
    {
        $sql = 'select var_dept_name, var_emp_name from tbl_dept, tbl_emp where tbl_dept.int_hod = tbl_emp.int_id order by var_dept_name limit ' . $start . ', ' . $limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

I want to implement it on my SQL query, but I don't know how to put limit:

```
public function get_results($search_term)
{
    // Use the Active Record class for safer queries.
    $this->db->select('*');                 
    $this->db->from('tbl_products');
    $this->db->like('name',$search_term);

    // Execute the query.
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // Return the results.
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. Add

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```

somewhere before executing the query with `$this->db->get();`

[Documentation on limit](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

Comment: thanks But can u pls help me with my pagination its not working ..n today its t last last for submission

Comment: foreach ($results as $val)

Comment: <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($deptlist); ++$i) { ?> have to implement this code to      
foreach ($results as $val) ......